# I'm making less money than what my job description

Tags: salary

When a new job title was created, my director showed me the description (without the salary listed) and asked if I was interested in the position. My current position's funding was ending, and I was wanting a new role anyways, so I accepted. I was promoted to the new role and had received a significant increase from it (22% increase).

However, two months into my position, when a few other candidates had been brought on board, our job description was handed out in a meeting, but this time the salary was listed. I noticed I'm making 10% less than the minimum salary that what was in the description.

Its now been almost 3 years and I'm still making less than what was on the minimum salary. I'm grateful for the promotion, but part of me feels a little cheated.

I want to talk to my director and supervisor about it, but I'm not sure what's the best way to go about it.

Comment: It is normal that anyone joining after you for the same position will have a slightly higher salary. Over time, the difference will increase.

Comment: if the standard sallary was told to you, why dont you simply ask your supervisor if there is a particular reason for you to not be making that

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an annual or 6-month review? If not, ask for one. And a formal one, where you can get documentation stating whether or not you are doing a satisfactory job, and if there are improvements your director would like you to make.

Start the review searching for these answers and seeking approval, then when it's your turn to talk about how you're feeling in the role, bring the job description with the salary listed and ask about it.

Find out:
Is this a different role than mine?
What is the career trajectory for this role? What do I need to do to reach the next step?

If you're feeling brave and know you're doing a good job:
Where did this compensation come from, and is there any reason I'm not eligible for this rate?

You may find that your director doesn't actually know you're being paid differently than someone else, and it's the company's mistake to disclose salary details for the same position if they're paying one person less. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, we do have a formal annual review. However, my organization had their performance review period in July then and at the time, I was only in the position for 3 months. Then the following year, the organization decided to push the review period to January. So I had my review in January & got a merit increase then, but it was still less than what I had expected. I've had great reviews, which is why I feel a little puzzled by this. I like the idea of asking about how the compensation came from and why I'm not eligible for the rate. At least then, I won't feel like I'm in the dark about it

Comment: PS The standard salary for the position was not shared with me until a few months after I was in the position.